# Shuffle a table in MySQL with a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure in MySQL that can shuffle all my records inside a table. So far this is what i have now.

```
/*
    SHUFFLE A TABLE PROCEDURE
*/

DELIMITER $$

USE `nologinsdb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `shuffle_record_table`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `shuffle_record_table`()
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS record_table2;

    CREATE TABLE record_table2 LIKE record_table;

    INSERT INTO record_table2 SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY RAND();

    DROP TABLE record_table;

    RENAME TABLE record_table2 TO record_table;
END$$

DELIMITER ;


CALL shuffle_record_table();
```

and i don't understand something

`SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY RAND()`

gives me random order, but when i inserting in the `record_table2` table it has the same order as the `record_table` table.

i don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it is the same order?   If you want to randomize, then create a field called 'sort' and populate it with random values then run your 'ORDER BY' on that field

Comment: i know that i can do that, but i have to do it this way, because that ORDER BY is from an different application that i cannot code it.

Comment: Did you see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html? And (with no sarcasm intended) if there is an 'ORDER BY' in another application, you can't expect to randomize the order.

Comment: yes, and the ideea is to create a second table from a randomized select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html 
they say that:

> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and **indexes defined in the original table**:

It means, that a primary key is also copied to a new table, and preservers the rows order.
Just drop the primary key in the new table :

```
CREATE TABLE record_table2 LIKE record_table;
ALTER TABLE record_table2 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
INSERT INTO record_table2 SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY RAND();
```

----- EDIT ----- 
If the above solution doesn't work since there is an auto_icrement on the primary key column, 
then try `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT * FROM y`, this doesn't copy indexes and keys:

```
create table x( 
  x int primary key auto_increment,
  y int );

insert into x( y ) values( 1 ), (3 ), (2),(5),(4);

select * from x;
+ ------ + ------ +
| x      | y      |
+ ------ + ------ +
| 1      | 1      |
| 2      | 3      |
| 3      | 2      |
| 4      | 5      |
| 5      | 4      |
+ ------ + ------ +

5 rows

create table y as select * from x order by rand();

select * from y;

+ ------ + ------ +
| x      | y      |
+ ------ + ------ +
| 2      | 3      |
| 4      | 5      |
| 3      | 2      |
| 1      | 1      |
| 5      | 4      |
+ ------ + ------ +

5 rows
```

Comment: Error Code: 1075
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
==> seems lie i cannot drop primary key, why?

Comment: So the ideea is that i must not create a table with `LIKE`, but rather create it directly from a `SELECT` stetelment with `AS`, right? Fascinating ... wow ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to shuffle rows in a table. You can shuffle them while retrieving the data using order by.

The physical order of the rows is of no interest to the user. The storage engine is placing the in the order of the index to optimize the access.

Comment: i know that i can do that, but i have to do it this way, because that ORDER BY is from an different application that i cannot code it.

Comment: @damian I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i said that i cannot ORDER BY an `order_id` column, because i cannot access that application source code, but someonelse has a good response to my problem, it appears that i should use `AS` instead `LIKE` ... i'm sorry i didn't read the whole documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use InnoDB tables, they are always stored in primary key order. So if you `SELECT` from the table without specifying any other `ORDER BY`, then you'll the rows in that order.

---

> Error Code: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key ==> seems lie i cannot drop primary key, why? – Damian

InnoDB requires that if you have an AUTO_INCREMENT column, it must be the first column in an index. Typically people define it as the primary key index, but if you drop the primary key, you must at least define a different index for it.

Example: create a test table that has an auto-increment primary key.

```
mysql> create table record_table (id int auto_increment primary key);

mysql> insert into record_table values (1), (2), (3);
```

It's not allowed to have an auto-increment column that is not part of any key.

```
mysql> alter table record_table drop primary key;
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; 
there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

If we drop the primary key but add a secondary key on the same column, this satisfies InnoDB.

```
mysql> alter table record_table drop primary key, add key (id);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.13 sec)
```

But if we try to make that column have *no* key, it's also an error.

```
mysql> alter table record_table drop key id;
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; 
there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

---

One workaround is to create an extra column in the table and assign random values to it, then you can ORDER BY that column.

```
mysql> alter table record_table add column sort float;

mysql> update record_table set sort = rand();

mysql> select * from record_table ;
+----+----------+
| id | sort     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 0.439593 |
|  2 | 0.416936 |
|  3 |   0.7659 |
+----+----------+

mysql> select * from record_table order by sort;
+----+----------+
| id | sort     |
+----+----------+
|  2 | 0.416936 |
|  1 | 0.439593 |
|  3 |   0.7659 |
+----+----------+
```

You can "reshuffle" the table without having to copy data back and forth, just UPDATE the random values.

```
mysql> update record_table set sort = rand();

mysql> select * from record_table order by sort;
+----+----------+
| id | sort     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 0.137319 |
|  3 | 0.329505 |
|  2 | 0.348292 |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: so if i switch to MyISAM it will be ok because of the storage engine?

Comment: Don't switch to MyISAM. It's basically a dead storage engine.

Comment: 1. For what i understand, there always must be a `key`

2. I know that i can use a column named `order_id`, but i cannot modify the source code of the application, it must be done in pure mysql.

3. What do you mean MyISAM is a dead storage engine? I know that MyISAM is faster then InnoDB, so that means that could be good in certain situations...

Comment: The relative speed of MyISAM is an old wives tale.  InnoDB outperforms MyISAM in almost all benchmarks.

Comment: @RickJames MyISAM might still be faster than InnoDB in edge cases like doing full table-scans. Or if one is still using a version of MySQL from 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Look i had same question here and the solution has:

```
CREATE TABLE origintable SELECT * FROM origintable2;
ALTER TABLE origintable2 DROP idfield;
CREATE TABLE origintable3 LIKE origintable2;
INSERT INTO origintable3 SELECT * FROM origintable2 ORDER BY RAND();
DROP TABLE origintable2;
ALTER TABLE origintable3 ADD COLUMN idfield INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
, ADD PRIMARY KEY (idfield);
RENAME TABLE origintable TO origintable_bkp;
RENAME TABLE origintable3 TO origintable;
DROP TABLE origintable3;
```

Works like a charm! new table, suffle data, same sctructure!

Hope helps somebody

Comment: Oh, thank you. It is a good ideea, i get it, but above `RENAME TABLE origintable TO origintable_bkp;` you may put `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS origintable_bkp` no?